# What to paste in when Responsive theme asks: "paste your shortcode, video or image"

Tags: wordpress, image, themes, responsive, shortcode

I am making a website using Responsive theme from Wordpress https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive/

Responsive has a box that is titled "Featured content" and the instructions are: "paste your shortcode, video or image source".

I need to display image there. I can't find any tutorials on that.

Also, I don't know how to set (in that theme? where?) which image is featured.

I saw that functions.php file has function responsive_page_featured_image() but when I type [responsive_page_featured_image] into that box, no picture gets displayed. Where do I set the featured image?

Wordpress summary of shortcodes does not have [image]... Other stuff it does have, like [gallery] seem to be made in Wordpress, not from the theme. 
https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/

REsponsive's link to their forum is broken...

SO what should I paste into that box?

Thanks!

Comment: The link to their forum worked for me at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/responsive/

Comment: Thanks that works! The link off the Responsive page gives 404 error

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are rendering the content as it is. So, I believe you can add `img` tag to display image. Example:

```
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/1" alt="" />
```